# Extracting contents from the table beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract out the contents inside a table on a website.

```
descriptions = []
sources = []
values = []

site = 'https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/prices.php' #address of the site 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'") 
driver.get(site)

soup_1 = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml') #clean up the site using beautiful soup
tables = soup_1.find_all('tbody') #script of interest
print(len(tables))  #count the scripts 


for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    print(len(rows))
    for row in rows:
        description = row.find('td', class_='s1')
        descriptions.append(descri_clean)

        source = row.find('td', class_='s2')
        sources.append(source_clean)

        value = row.find('td', class_='d1') #find the row that gives the data
        values.append(value_clean) #compile it all together 

driver.close()
```

I have been trying  to get clean text form the table however the data extracted looks like this.

```
<td class="s1" rowspan="3">Crude Oil<br/> ($/barrel)</td>
```

While i want something  like just  ''Crude Oil ($/barrel)

When i tried

```
description = row.find('td', class_='s1').text.renderContents()
descriptions.append(descri_clean)
```

The error showed up

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'renderContents'
```

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: @QHarr I have updated the link.

Comment: And you want all  tables?

Comment: not all i only want some but i don't know how to only extract out some  of them.

Comment: which ones do you want?

Comment: I only want the description and values
Crude Oil ($/barrel) - Nymex Apr,
Ethanol ($/gallon) - CBOT Apr,
Los Angeles,
 WTI,
Brent,
Louisiana Light,

Comment: Los Angeles appears twice

Answer (score 1):

You can use just requests. You can filter out your values by doing string matching on expected values for certain class attributes when looping table rows. I set the two tables of interest into separate variables which are lists of the rows within those tables. The tables on the page each have their own distinct class identifier for the table number e.g. t1, t2 ......

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/prices.php')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table1 = soup.select('.t1 tr')
table2 = soup.select('.t2 tr')
for item in table1:
    if 'Crude Oil ($/barrel) - Nymex Apr' in item.text:
        rowInfo = [td.text for td in item.select('td')]
        print(rowInfo)
    elif 'Ethanol ($/gallon) - CBOT Apr' in item.text:
        rowInfo = [td.text for td in item.select('td')]
        print(rowInfo)

for item in table2:
    if len(item.select('td')) == 4:
        header = item.select_one('td.s1').text
    if item.select_one('td.s2'):
        if item.select_one('td.s2').text in ['WTI','Brent','Louisiana Light','Los Angeles'] and header in ['Crude Oil ($/barrel)','Gasoline (RBOB) ($/gallon)']:
            rowInfo = [td.text for td in item.select('td')]
            print(rowInfo)
```

Comment: this code works but i want to save it in a csv file do it just change print row info and put it in a empty list? @QHarr

Comment: Yes. Append to list, convert to df and use df.to_csv